# aws 料金発生　対処方法

Tags: aws

現在rails勉強中で、awsを使い出したのですが、気がついたら料金が発生していてどうしたらいいかわからないので質問させていただきます。

請求情報を見ると、

> EC2 $29.60
>   RDS $3.11
>   DataTransfer  $0
>   S3 $0
>   税 $2.61

となっていまして、月末までの予想が$98.28となっています。

練習がてらに色々と設定を試したり、railsのデプロイしたかったりなどでいくつかインスタンスなど作っていまして、
今月初あたりにec2インスタンスとrdsインスタンスが複数立ち上がったままだったので急いで削除したり停止にしてたりはしました。その時は＄１０くらいだったと思うのですが、それ以来全くawsは使っていなかったのですが料金が増えていました。

この場合どうしたら料金を抑えられるでしょうか？

参考までに、
EC2のリソース：

> 0 個の実行中のインスタンス
>   0 Dedicated Host
>   8 個のボリューム
>   6 個のキーペア
>   0 個のプレイスメントグループ
>   2 個の Elastic IP
>   0 個のスナップショット
>   3 個のロードバランサー
>   18 個のセキュリティグループ

RDSのリソース:

> DB インスタンス (3/40)
>   ストレージ割り当て (60.00 GB/100.00 TB)
>   DB インスタンス上限を引き上げるには、こちらをクリックしてください
>   リザーブドインスタンス (0/40)
>   スナップショット (41)
>   手動 (2/100)
>   自動 (23)
>   最近のイベント (12)
>   イベントサブスクリプション (0/20)
>   パラメータグループ (3)
>   デフォルト (1)
>   カスタム (2/100)
>   オプショングループ (1)
>   デフォルト (1)
>   カスタム (0/20)
>   サブネットグループ (4/50)
>   サポートされているプラットフォーム VPC
>   デフォルトネットワーク vpc-1529db72

となっています。

これからrailsで作ったアプリケーションの１つはデプロイしたいとは思っているのですが、課金が怖くなっています。料金の抑え方を教えていただきたいですのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: ボリューム数が多くないです？ボリュームタイプとサイズによっても変わりますが全部使っているんでしょうか？`請求ダッシュボード＞請求書＞月選択＞詳細＞AWSサービス料金＞ElasticComputeCloud＞Zone名＞EBS`の項目はどれくらいの金額になっていますか？

Answer (score 5):

EC2/RDSインスタンスは削除したということなので、恐らく、ELB x3つで60ドル/月弱、あとは、EBSボリューム、EIP で請求が発生してると思います。まずは、「請求書」のページで請求額の明細を確認してみてください。

請求額を安くするポイントですが

- EC2のインスタンス：使い終わったら止めるまたは消す。
- RDSのインスタンス：使い終わったら削除して最終バックアップを残す。再び使うときはリストアする。（結構面倒なので操作手順をスクリプト化しておくのがお勧めです）
- ELB：使い終わったら消す
- EBSボリューム：不要なボリュームを削除。作るときは容量は必用最低限の少なめで作る。（足りなかったら後から拡張できます）
- EIP：未使用状態で保有すると若干ですが請求が発生するので、グローバルIPが変わるとまずい場合以外は、使い終わったら消す。

また、12ヶ月間の無料枠がありますが、それぞれ条件がありますので内容をよく確認されることをお勧めします。
ご参考）https://aws.amazon.com/jp/free/

作ったり消したりが面倒という場合は、SDKやCLIでスクリプト化するか、CloudFormerでテンプレート化するというのもオススメです。

Answer (score 2):

**今回の件がこれに当てはまるかどうかはわかりません**が、
AWSの予測はラフに計算されており、月初にお金がかかる処理があると、比較的多めに計算されているように感じます。（私の計算よりも予測が高くなったので問い合わせたことがあります。とはいえ、いつまでもラフかどうかわからないので油断できないと思いますが）

こちらの資料が参考になると思います。
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/high-aws-cost-forecast/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-forecast.html

あくまで予測に関してはそういう傾向があるというだけで、ご自身で計算できるようなり、計画的に使うことにこしたことはないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

今後もテスト用に起動したインスタンスの消し忘れ等があるかもしれません。
対策の一つに「請求金額がある一定値を超えたらメール等に通知する」という方法があります。

- [予想 AWS 請求額をモニタリングする請求アラームの作成 - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html)

Comment: 過度な請求はひとまずこれで対処できるかと

Answer (score 0):

慌てて停止した現状を書き込んでも意味はなく、EC2 $29.60の内訳を確認することでしょう。つまり、インスタンスサイズ、台数、稼働時間を確認した上で、今後、どの程度を稼働させるかの話だと思います。